# How energizing/effective are Turmeric supplements? They are often advertised on energy drinks

Tags: supplement, effectiveness, energy, energy-drinks, turmeric

I've been studying for exams lately, and as much as I hate to admit (because I know how bad energy drinks are for people), I've been consuming some energy drinks, and I've noticed that quite a lot of them highlight that they contain turmeric.

How effective is turmeric in energy drinks?

Are there more natural ways to consume turmeric? Like do they exist in foods?